# SQL (mysql database) how to ban the number from showing up in the output if it meets a certain number in the same row

Tags: sql, mysql

| pnom | ocinka | snom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 |

Needs to select numbers from the column snom(3)
the conditions are:

1. pnom(1) column must be 3
2. ocinka(2) column must be an any other number then 3.
3. if  ocinka(2) = 3 then the number that stands in the same row in snom(3) column must be banned from showing up in the output.

i have tried for an hour. help please

in theory the output must be - 1,6,3 in any order

not 7 because it meets 3 in 6's row

Comment: Please read : [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why not use a `WHERE` condition for this? Also, what do you mean by "meets 3 in 6's row"?

Comment: i added an image with an example of filled with numbers table, by "meets" i mean that number in column 3 stands in the same row with number 3 in the column 2

Comment: also i dont get how to solwe this with WHERE

Comment: Please add all clarification **in text form**, like the table structure and sample data (as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements). Also, are you sure this problem is related to MySQL Workbench?

Comment: added the table in text form

Comment: SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE pnom = 3 AND ocinka <> 3 
^ this gets 1 and 2 done .. for 3 you need a subquery or you you use this and then
run a second one to remove all the cases that do not belong such as the result of 7 in your example.

Comment: yes, the last part is the one i cant figure out. how to run it second one to remove all the cases that do not belong such as the result of 7 in my example

Comment: I don't understand, by selecting rows with `pnom = 3` and `ocinka != 3` then the only distinct `snom` values are 1, 3 and 6 - which is your expected result. Why do you need to specify 7 as not being included since it's already excluded by `ocinka != 3`.

Comment: `select distinct snom from mytable where pnom = 3 and ocinka != 3` : 1,3,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get all snom that are not in your criteria and the eliminate them, from the results

```
WITH unwanted as (SELECT DISTiNCT `snom` FROM mytable WHERE `ocinka` = 3 AND  `pnom` = 3)
SELECT DISTINCT `snom` FROM mytable WHERE `pnom` = 3 AND `snom` NOT IN (SELECT `snom` FROM unwanted)
```

| snom |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 6 |
| 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ek3TQjSc)